# Implementing Lazy<T> in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In .NET, there is the [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) type which for example is useful for implementing lazy loading and caching. I'm unaware of an equivalent solution for TypeScript, so I rolled my own.

```
export interface Factory<TResult> { () : TResult; }

export class Lazy<T> {
    factoryOutput : T;
    isValueSet : boolean;

    constructor(private factory : Factory<T>) { }    

    get value() {
        if (!this.isValueSet) {
            this.factoryOutput = this.factory();
            this.isValueSet = true;
        }
        return this.factoryOutput;
    }
}
```

Having to implement it myself makes me wonder:

- Am I overlooking an existing solution for TypeScript?
- Is there something fundamentally wrong with my reasoning wanting to have a .NET styled `Lazy<T>` in TypeScript?

Comment: There's nothing like that in typescript as the language doesn't offer any helper/utils. But javascript has [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which kinda sounds like what you're describing.

Comment: I find that since functions are first class citizens, passing lambdas usually fits the bill: example: `log(() => HeavyFuncThatWillOnlyBeExecutedForProperLogLevel())`. For the more complicated stuff `immutable.js` provides lazy Seqs

Comment: Thanks for the response, guys! Nitzan, `Promise` has indeed run through my mind as a possible alternative but the problem is that I wish to access my lazily loaded value synchronously and cache it for subsequent access. For the same reason, Bruno, just passing in a lambda doesn't completely fit the bill either.

I think that `Promise` is probably my best option seeing as synchronous evaluation of the heavy functions will eventually tear down performance, but that will also probably impact architectural design. I'm likely answering my own question here, but let's see what else comes up!

Comment: Well then stick to your solution, there's nothing wrong wit it

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply done by declaring a `Lazy<T>` type as a function return a value with type `T`, like this:

```ts
type Lazy<T> = () => T;
```

You can then continue to implement lazy data types, this could be a `LazyList` implementation (supporting an infinite amount of elements):

```ts
type LazyList<T> = {
   head: Lazy<T>,
   tail: Lazy<LazyList<T>>
} | null
```

where null represents an empty list.

Then you can create a `range` function:

```ts
function range(min: number = 0, max: number = Infinity) {
   if (max <= min) return null;
   else return {
      head: () => head;
      tail: () => range(min+1, max);
   }
}
```

This list type is similar to the one in Haskell, where every list is structured like this.